# Karate: Can we use "match each" twice in same line for 2 different assertions?

Tags: match, karate, assert

Basically, I want to achieve the below assertions in a single statement

```
* match each obj[*].id != ''
* match each obj[*].name != ''
```

-> obj: its a list of JSON objects returned as the response to an API

The below code snippet does not work.

```
* match each obj[*].id != '' && each obj[*].name != ''
```

can this be achieved in karate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are un-necessarily using JsonPath like `[*]`. Best practice in Karate is to express data as JSON. For example:

```
* def response = [{ a: 1, b: 'x' }, { a: 2, b: 'y' }]
* match each response == { a: '#number', b: '#string' }
```

So yes you can achieve what you want:

```
* match each obj contains { id: "#? _ != ''", name: "#? _ != ''" }
```